# How to locate a specific slide using a certain layout in Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

I have a 38 slide presentation.  When examining the Master theme, I can see that there is 1 slide using a specific layout "Big Number".  But I don't see any slide that is using that layout.  I have gone through every slide and made sure each is using the correct layout.  How can I locate this seemingly "phantom" slide so that I can either delete it or change it to use the correct layout?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking almost for the same, but not figured out how to find and list all layout names it the Master.

Probably you should use script to find specific layouts[] object for (Page)

The layouts in the presentation. A layout is a template that determines how content is arranged and styled on the slides that inherit from that layout.
From https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations?hl=en

[image: diagram depicts the relationship between presentations, pages, and page elements as types in the Slides API]

[See more about Pages, Page Elements, and Properties](https://developers.google.com/slides/concepts/page-elements)

[There is some code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47387288/3359687) for the layouts search:

```
// The following line opens my presentation
var presentation = SlidesApp.openById('PresentationID');
// this will return an array of all the layouts
var layouts = presentation.getLayouts();

//if your first array item is the office layout
var newSlide = presentation.appendSlide(layouts[0]);

//Orelse you can search for your layout
var selectedLayout;
for(var item in layouts)
{
   //Logger.log(layouts[item].getLayoutName());
   if(layouts[item].getLayoutName() =='CUSTOM_1')
   {
     selectedLayout = layouts[item];
   }
}
```

Comment: I’m sorry but I don’t understand how this is an answer to the question asked…?

Answer (score 0):

With your presentation open in Slides, chose menu item Slide > Edit Theme. Then select a particular slide layout. Once selected, all of the slides using that layout will be highlighted (bounded in yellow) in the thumbnail views on the left hand side of the page. You may need to scroll up and down through the thumbnails to find the slide(s) using the selected layout.